# Hear and Know Here and Now

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

> Said the cop to the crook who was making a haul:
>   "You seem like a pattern that's seen on a wall.
>   When a jailer has pity and unlocks your gate,
>   You may well rejoice in the change of your state."
>
> It may start in a flower, end towers with bells
>   And is in the reversal a seer foretells.

For an answer, I will accept any one of a small set of English words.

Comment: That was a fun one!

Comment: @Deusovi We aim to please.

Comment: "We"? I *knew* you were a hivemind!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The possible answers are

> FREEZE and its homophones.

Said the cop to the crook who was making a haul:

> Policemen say "**Freeze!**" to criminals.

"You seem like a pattern that's seen on a wall.

> A "**frieze**" pattern is a pattern that is equivalent to itself by translation and/or rotation; basically, a wallpaper pattern.

When a jailer has pity and unlocks your gate,

> A jailer **frees** you when he unlocks your gate.

You may well rejoice in the change of your state."

> **Freezing** is a change of state from liquid to solid.

It may start in a flower, end towers with bells

> A **frees**ia is a type of flower, and bell towers are called "bel**fries**".

And is in the reversal a seer foretells.

> Reverse "a **seer f**oretells" and you can see (and hear!) "FREES".